# Chain map with object on Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm creating an object for each line read of a file inside a map.

On a chained map, I try to access a variable from that object, but I receive an empty variable. 
I'm using Spark Streamer

```
//..
val lines = ssc.textFileStream("CSVs/")
lines.map(line => new UserData(line)) 
     .map(userData => userData.myVar)
.print()
```

And my UserData Class

```
class UserData(csvLine: String) extends Serializable{
  { 
     myVar = csvLine
  }
  var myVar = ""
}
```

Comment: With your definition of `UserData` it is clear that `myVar` will always be an empty string (because you assign an empty string to it)

Comment: What about the constructor? But you are right, I was doing something wrong, as Scala declares myVar as empty, then I assign the line (I added a println on that scope and it gets assignes), and again it sets it to empty. I moved the assign to a method and it works as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing something wrong, as Scala declares myVar as empty, then I assign the line (I added a println on that scope and it gets assigned), and again it sets it to empty. I moved the assign to a method and it works as intended.

```
//..
val lines = ssc.textFileStream("CSVs/")
lines.map(line => new UserData().init(line)) 
     .map(userData => userData.myVar)
.print()
///...


class UserData() extends Serializable{
  var myVar = ""      
   def init(csvLine: String): UserData=
   { 
     myVar = csvLine
     return this
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case class

```
case class UserData(csvLine: String)
```

I'm not sure why you have `userData.myVar` in your code, it should probably be like this:

```
val lines = ssc.textFileStream("CSVs/")
lines.map(line => UserData(line)) 
  .map(userData => userData.csvLine)
  .print()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

In addition, `textFileStream` only monitor a folder when the files are being added or updated. If you just want to read the files you can use `spark.read` or `sparkContext.textFile`.

Comment: Also since textFileStream returns a Dstream, I added at the end .foreachRDD, still not working.

Comment: I think your problem is that `textFileStream` only considers new files, updated the answer. You can try to copy the files to the directory while the spark job is running to test if it's working.

Comment: It's reading the contents of the file, when I print inside of the UserData constructor it shows the correct output.

Comment: Try using the case class I suggested (can remove the `new` keyword as well), it could be the problem is related to the `var`. Also, can you include the code that you used when printing the correct value?